# How to create a panel based on a long list of table in r

Tags: r

I have a data set like the following:

```
wk    name      score
3   - Davide -  3.070000
6   - Davide -  3.460000
7   - Davide -  3.480000
48  -Cringe-    2.773333
79  -Fabynsane- 2.330000
69  -PiDjO-     2.070000
61  -sjb-       2.310000
```

I want to use this information to construct a panel like the following:

```
    name1 name2 name3 ...
wk1 
wk2
wk3 
...
```

I have tried dcast in reshape:

```
panel.num = dcast(data, name + wk ~ score)
```

but it gives me a panel like the following and this is apparently not the one I want:

```
    Authorname  wk.list 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13          
2   - Davide -  3   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
3   - Davide -  6   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I am wondering what went wrong and how I could fix this issue. Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing `wk ~ name`, ie

```
dat <- data.frame(wk=sample(1:100, 10), 
                  name=sample(c("Davide", "Cringe", "Fabynsane"), 10, rep=T),
                  score=runif(10, 2, 3))

library(reshape2)
dcast(dat, wk ~ name)
#    wk   Cringe   Davide Fabynsane
# 1   8       NA 2.225543        NA
# 2  12       NA       NA  2.958040
# 3  46       NA 2.659209        NA
# 4  47       NA 2.086529        NA
# 5  59       NA       NA  2.287232
```

Answer (score 1):

Other options include

```
library(tidyr)
spread(dat, name, score)
```

Or `reshape` from `base R`

```
reshape(dat, idvar='wk', timevar='name', direction='wide')
```